# MultiLevel Inheritance, Can class C inherit Class A?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a quick question regarding Multi Level Inheritance.
Let say I have 3 classes, class A, class B and class C.

```
Class B extends from Class A
Class C extends from Class B
```

my question is
does Class C inherits(have all the function in) Class A as well, since it's inherit Class B and Class B inherits Class A

Comment: Simple answer..yes..you could've tried this on your own as well

Comment: Why don't you instantiate `C` and check? :)

Comment: yeah. Class C will have the functionality of A and B

Comment: yes, it will inherit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since  B inherit A, it make sense that class C will include both B and A as well

Answer (score 0):

As long as what B inherits from A makes it, its own, then when C extends B will take all posseced by it, so that icnludes what B took from A. So the answer is yes, C will inherit all function of A and B as long as B extends A.